# MySQL Where IN while also looking for anything that has the value with any amount of 0's preceeding it

Tags: mysql, where-clause

MySQL Where IN while also looking for anything that has the value with any amount of 0's preceeding it.

I am trying to do a

```
select * 
from table 
where acol IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

I would also like to return anything that has `001`, `0002`, `03`, `00004` etc.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the datatype? If it's a number type, leading zeroes don't exist.

Comment: If it's a character type, cast it to a number: `WHERE CAST(acol AS DECIMAL) IN ...`

Comment: @Barmar why decimal and not integer?

Comment: @Barmar - the cast **WHERE CAST(acol AS DECIMAL) IN ...** will gives you a full table scan

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `INTEGER` isn't an allowed type for `CAST`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: @BerndBuffen Yes, it will. If you know a better way, post it.

Comment: The right solution is to store numbers, not strings with leading zeroes.

Comment: or `...acol+0 IN...`

Comment: `CAST(acol AS unsigned)`

Comment: I think the code as written will actually coerce the string to a number automatically.

Comment: When I use cast to decimal it returns anything with that number  ie: '02-100002' instead of just 0002 or 02

Comment: same with acol+0

Comment: Juan dont know how to thumb up this but that answer worked, much appreciated..   Used select * from table where trim(leading '0' from acol) in ('1','2','3')

Answer (score 1):

According to description as mentioned into above question to perform comparison with numeric values having leading zeroes,if data type of column is defined as integer, then the value having leading zeroes will be stored into column without leading zeroes and hence equality of values into equality expression or into IN expression into where clause as a part of SQL select statement will  evaluate to true.

Else if data type of column is defined as varchar ,then value having leading zeroes will be stored according to its original format with leading zeroes into column and to perform comparison with values having leading zeroes  you need to use like operator into where clause as a part of SQL select statement.  Alternatively varchar column value can be casted into integer data type  using MYSQL CAST function and upon performing comparison with type casted value into where clause as a part of SQL Select Statement ,equality of values will evaluate to true.

```
select *
    from table
where CAST(acol as unsigned) IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work by using  select * from table where trim(leading '0' from acol) in ('1','2','3')

Comment: Rubin's answer is valid. You should post your solution as an answer too and let others vote. Once a clear leader, mark it as accepted answer for benefit of others searching for this in future.